# Can $U\Sigma U^T \preceq UVSV^TU^T$ lead to $ UVS^{-1}V^TU^T \preceq U\Sigma^{-1} U^T$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Can $U\Sigma U^T \preceq UVSV^TU^T$ lead to  $  UVS^{-1}V^TU^T \preceq U\Sigma^{-1} U^T$?

where $UU^T=U^TU=VV^T=V^TV=I$ and $\Sigma, S$ are square matrix only with positive elements in its diagonal and the other elements are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general, when $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices, the followings are equivalent:

- $A\preceq B$,
- $0\preceq B-A$,
- $0\preceq B^{-1/2}(B-A)B^{-1/2}=I-B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$,
- all eigenvalues of the positive definite and real orthogonally diagonalisable matrix $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ are bounded above by $1$,
- all eigenvalues of the positive definite and real orthogonally diagonalisable matrix $B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}$ are bounded below by $1$,
- $0\preceq B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}-I=B^{1/2}(A^{-1}-B^{-1})B^{1/2}$,
- $0\preceq A^{-1}-B^{-1}$,
- $B^{-1}\preceq A^{-1}$.

Comment: Many thanks. BTW, If B or A don't have its inverse, then are there any similar claims for the pseudo-inverse?

Comment: @olivia No. Consider, e.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$ and $B=A+I$. Then $A^+-B^{-1}=\pmatrix{1/4&1/4\\ 1/4&1/4}-\pmatrix{2/3&-1/3\\ -1/3&2/3}$ is indefinite.

Comment: Many  thanks. If $0\preceq A\preceq B$, $B$ has its inverse, and the column space of $A$ belongs to that of $B$, then what is the relation between $A^\dagger$ and $B^{-1}$?

Comment: @olivia The statement that "the column space of $A$ belongs to that of $B$" is redundant: when $B$ is invertible, its column space is the whole Euclidean space, so it must contain the column space of $A$. Anyway, $C=A^\dagger-B^{-1}$ is negative semidefinite on $\ker A$ and positive semidefinite on $(\ker A)^\perp$ (= column space of $A$). So, when both $\ker A$ and $(\ker A)^\perp$ are nonzero, $C$ is indefinite.